# Construction of polymorphic classes

Tags: c++

I have a question about the way classes using inheritance are constructed. In the example below, the call to the `Base` constructor is dependent on a function implemented in the `Derived` class. This function is again dependent on the `Derived` member `generator`, which will not be initialized until after the `Base` constructor call.

If the `Base` class is constructed first, won't the variable `Base::in_` contain garbage data?

```
class Derived
    : public Base
{

    Derived()
        : Base(get_data()),
          generator(5) {}

    Generator generator;

    int get_data() { return generator.get_some_data(); }
};

class Base
{
    Base(int in)
         : in_(in) {}

    int in_;

}
```

Comment: Nice question. But the terms are awry. Can we replace polymorphism with inheritance? As for the answer, I think there's UB in here somewhere.

Comment: If the return-value of function `get_some_data` depends on **non-static** member variables of class `Generator`, then the answer is yes.

Comment: You'r right. I changed the wording from polymorphic to inheritance. Thanks

Comment: @barakmanos: I would even says UB as calling a method from an uninitialized value.

Comment: @Jarod42: `generator` is not a value. It's an object which contains values (AKA non-static member variables).

Comment: @barakmanos: Which contains uninitialized values and/or objects. so depending of the method, it may be UB and not just garbage.

Answer (score 2):

First, nothing in your code is polymorphic. Polymorphism is about virtual functions.

Next, your *class* `Base` depends on nothing. Look between `class Base {` and the matching `}`, there's nothing in there that depends on anything outside.

What happens is the construction of the `Base` *subobject* within `Derived` depends on another member of Derived, which is constructed after `Base`. Your analysis is basically correct, it's a real problem and it needs to be solved by refactoring your classes.

The easiest way is two-stage initialization of Base (the following is pseudocode and probably will not compile):

```
class Base {
    Base(int in = 0) : in_(in) {}
    void set(int in) { in_ = in; }
    int in_;
};

class Derived : public Base {    
    Derived() : Base(), generator(5) {
      Base::set(generator);
    }
    ...
};
```

Another method is moving the dependency to another base class:

```
class Base2 { ... generator implemented here ... };
class Derived : public Base2, public Base {
  Derived() : Base2(5), Base(Base2::generator) {}
};
```

Comment: +1 for for pointing out that the given example in the question does not contain polymorphism nor dependencies

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I changed the wording in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the standard says, but this is clearly a matter of what is the value of `generator` when `get_data()` is called, as it would be if you call it from somewhere else then the constructor.

Code called from within a constructor is no way different to other code.

My guess is that get_data() is called before generator is constructed and thus you will get a NULL exception at runtime.
Another point to mention is that the base class is of course being constructed first. It is the base class. `Derived` IS A `Base`, it has a field `in_`.

As a rule of thumb it is always a good pattern to:

1. Avoid method calls from the constructor. Use an additional init method for that.
2. In any case beware of circular constructor calls.

You also could make `get_data` abstract in `Base` and then call it within the `Init()` of `Base` which would IMHO be the right way to implement a dependency to child classes as you call it.

```
class Derived
    : public Base
{

    Derived()
        : Base(),
          generator(5) {}

    Generator generator;

    virtual int get_data() { return generator.get_some_data(); }
};

class Base
{
    Base()
    {

    }

    Init() {
       in_ = get_data();}   
    int in_;

    virtual int get_data() = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Order of calling constructors/destructors in inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539282/order-of-calling-constructors-destructors-in-inheritance)

The constructor for Base will be called before any members of Derived are initialized.  So generator will not have been initialized when get_data() is called.

Basically, Base will be initialized with garbage.