# pointer issue in classes

Tags: qt, class, pointers

I have this two classes: board.h and scene.h.When I run program like this everything works fine:
scene.cpp

```
scene::scene()
{
  basescene=new QGraphicsScene;
  additem();

}

void scene::additem()
{
    board *_board=new board;
    QPixmap boarditem (":/images/board.png");
    _board->setPixmap(boarditem);
    basescene->addItem(_board);
}
```

scene.h

```
class scene:public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    scene();
    QGraphicsScene *basescene;
    void additem();
};
```

board.h

```
class board:public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    board();
};
```

board.cpp

```
board::board()
{

}
```

But when i run it like this:

scene.h

```
class scene:public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    scene();
    QGraphicsScene *basescene;

};
```

scene.cpp

```
scene::scene()
{
  basescene=new QGraphicsScene;
  board _board;

}
```

board.h

```
class board:public QGraphicsPixmapItem,public scene
{
public:
    board();
    void additem();
    board *_board;
};
```

board.cpp

```
board::board()
{
   additem();
}

void board::additem()
{
board *_board=new board;
QPixmap boarditem (":/images/board.png");
_board->setPixmap(boarditem);
basescene->addItem(_board);
}
```

The program crashes and debugger says that the error is in  scene class and the code has a segment fault.I googling and it said that is some pointer issue... I'm newbie in c++ and debug thing and sorry about my bad english.

Comment: There is a mess in your code. You can completely remove the code working well, but put full code which fails. For example, where is the constructor of `chessscene` ?

Comment: I edit the post that's not the problem... I realy tired..didn't see that issue in post so sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inherited class `board` from `scene`.
When you create an instance of `board` the `scene` constructor is executed, then the `board` constructor is executed.
But in the `scene` constructor you create a new instance of board. And `scene` constructor of this new instance creates another instance of board. And so on till infinity.

If you need more info about constuctors calling:
[Order of calling constructors/destructors in inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539282/order-of-calling-constructors-destructors-in-inheritance)

EDIT:
Actually if it has overcome this issue and walk further it would come to the `board` constructor which calls `addItem` which creates another `board` instance. In the constructor of this new instance `addItem` will be called again and it will try to create another one `board` and again, and again.

So you have a couple of recursive constructor calls.