# Change the order of constructors in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am struggling with class inheritance construction order. Let's say I have these two classes:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    const int CONSTANT_A;
    A(const int constant) : CONSTANT_A(constant) {
    }
    void write() {
        std::cout << CONSTANT_A;
    }
};


class B : public A {
public:
    const int CONSTANT_B = 3;
    B() :A(CONSTANT_B) {
        write();
    }
};
```

When a new object `B` is created, `CONSTANT_A` is not 3 because class inheritance [constructors order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539330/7354030) works as following:

- Construction always starts from the base class. If there are multiple base classes then, it starts from the left most base.
- Then it comes the turn for member fields. They are initialized in the order they are declared.
- At the last the class itself is constructed.
- The order of destructor is exactly reverse.

Is there a way to force member constants to initialize first?. Which is the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: `B() : A(3), CONSTANT_B(3) {}` will ensure the members are initialised as intended.   There is no way to make `CONSTANT_B` be initialised before `A`s constructor though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constant `B::CONSTANT_B` can be `static`, since it does not depend on a constructor argument.

`static`s are initialised before your class objects are constructed (unless those are `static` too!).

```
struct B : A
{
    static const int CONSTANT_B = 3;

    B() : A(CONSTANT_B)
    {
        write();
    }
};
```

If `B::CONSTANT_B` itself took its value from a constructor argument, you'd probably have to name that argument twice in the *ctor-member-initialiser*. There are no trivial workarounds for that as far as I can imagine.

```
struct B : A
{
    const int CONSTANT_B;

    B(const int constant)
       : A(constant)
       , CONSTANT_B(constant)
    {
        write();
    }
};
```

Comment: There is apparently some [support for initialising a base from a member in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/utility/doc/html/base_from_member.html), but I've never used it or studied it in detail.

Comment: @Angew: Hmm, interesting perhaps. Liable to confuse more than help, IMO