# In Google Test, can I call GetParam() from the constructor?

Tags: c++, googletest

The Google Test C++ unit testing framework provides the ability to do [parameterised tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests). To access the parameter of a given test, the docs tell me to derive a subclass and call `GetParam()`:

```
class FooTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<const char*> {
  // You can implement all the usual fixture class members here.
  // To access the test parameter, call GetParam() from class
  // TestWithParam<T>.
};
```

I cannot find anything more specific than this in either the docs or the source code (inasmuch as I understand it).

Exactly where (or when) can I call `GetParam()`? I know I can call it in the body of a `TEST_P(...) { ... }` macro, but what about:

- In the `SetUp()` method for `FooTest()`?
- In the constructor for `FooTest()`?
- In the intialisation list for `FooTest()`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. 
You can assume `GetParam()` is method of `::testing::TestWithParam` base class.

```
class FooTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<const char*> {
  std::string name;
  FooTest() : name(GetParam()) {} 
};
```

With [C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B11/info) - you can even just initialize members directly in class:

```
class FooTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<const char*> {
  std::string name = GetParam();
};
```

Comment: Ooh, nice (the C++11 syntax, I didn't know that). I was confused because while I know I can treat `GetParam()` as a base class method, I wasn't sure *when* whatever `GetParam()` returns is initialised (eg. at construction or in a later call through some GTest magic).

Comment: You might assume - that base class is already constructed when you start constructing your members - read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539282/order-of-calling-constructors-destructors-in-inheritance